# How to convert tree json to nested Object in js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I converted a nested object into tree JSON format but now I need to convert it back to a nested object I tried so many ways but not working as expected. while converting nested object JSON I used recursion to achieve but here is how to operate it with the object.

I really appreciate your help, Thanks

```
input : 
     [
      {
        "name": "DI",
        "children": [
          {
            "name": "t",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "tID",
                "ir": true,
                "is": false
              },
              {
                "name": "tTime",
                "ir": false,
                "is": false
              }
            ],
            "ir": false,
            "is": false
          },
          {
            "name": "i",
            "children": [
              {
                "name": "idu",
                "ir": false,
                "is": false
              },
              {
                "name": "il",
                "ir": false,
                "is": false
              },
              {
                "name": "ibId",
                "children": [
                  {
                    "name": "ib1",
                    "ir": false,
                    "is": false
                  },
                  {
                    "name": "ib2",
                    "ir": false,
                    "is": false
                  }
                ],
                "ir": false,
                "is": false
              }
            ],
            "ir": false,
            "is": false
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

expected o/p:

```
{
   "DI":{
      "t":{
         "tID":{
            "ir":true,
            "is":false
         },
         "tTime":{
            "ir":false,
            "is":false
         },
         "ir":false,
         "is":false
      },
      "i":{
         "idu":{
            "ir":false,
            "ir":false
         },
         "il":{
            "ir":false,
            "is":false
         },
         "ibId":{
            "ib1":{
               "ir":false,
               "is":false
            },
            "ib2":{
               "ir":false,
               "is":false
            },
            "ir":false,
            "is":false
         },
         "ir":false,
         "is":false
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: where is `"idx": 0,` in your expected output !?

Comment: that's not needed while adding input JSON mistakenly added

Comment: @PrashanthkumarR did you check our answers?

Comment: @Apostolos , Thanks it's working as expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this recursive function:

```js
const toObject = (arr) =>
    Object.assign(...arr.map(({name, children, ...rest}) =>
        ({ [name]: Object.assign(rest, children && toObject(children)) })
    ));

// Example run:
const input =[{"name": "DI","children": [{"name": "t","children": [{"name": "tID","ir": true,"is": false},{"name": "tTime","ir": false,"is": false}],"ir": false,"is": false},{"name": "i","idx": 0,"children": [{"name": "idu","ir": false,"is": false},{"name": "il","ir": false,"is": false},{"name": "ibId","children": [{"name": "ib1","ir": false,"is": false},{"name": "ib2","ir": false,"is": false}],"ir": false,"is": false}],"ir": false,"is": false}]}];
const result = toObject(input);
console.log(result);
```

### Explanation

`arr.map` will iterate over the given array and return an array of the same length by applying a callback to each element. The callback takes an object as argument and immediately assigns some properties to local variables: `({name, children, ...rest})`. `rest` will be a copy of the original object, but without the `name` and `children` properties, which have been captured in separate variables.

The callback then returns an object. The parentheses around that object are needed to make clear that the opening brace belongs to an object literal, and not a statement block.

`[name] :` creates a property in that new object, that has a dynamically determined name (look up [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names)). This new object gets the value of `rest` which maybe gets extended with more, and that is why `Object.assign(rest)` is called.

If there is no `children` property in the original object, then the expression `children &&` will be undefined, and then `Object.assign` will just evaluate to `rest` without any mutation, but if `children` is an array, then `children && toObject(children)` will make the recursive call and return the corresponding object. In that case `Object.assign` will merge that object into `rest` so the properties are combined into one object.

So, the object returned by `Object.assign` is `rest` with possibly some nested objects coming from recursion. This object becomes the value of the dynamic `[name]` property.

Finally, that `arr.map` will thus return these new objects, and they each become separate arguments to the outer call of `Object.assign` because of the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (`...`). This will merge all those "little" objects into one combined object, which is returned to the caller.

Comment: the main obj outside  ir: true, is: false  also we want to add so how  we can add in this method

Comment: nothing wrong with this method but ex - {name:"t", children:[{name:"t1"}], ir:true, is:true} --> last ir:true, is:true  we are not considering in this method right

Comment: Ah, I hadn't noticed those extra properties. Updated my answer.

Comment: if you don't mind can you please explain the above code

Comment: Added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = '[ { "name": "DI", "children": [ { "name": "t", "children": [ { "name": "tID", "ir": true, "is": false }, { "name": "tTime", "ir": false, "is": false } ], "ir": false, "is": false }, { "name": "i", "idx": 0, "children": [ { "name": "idu", "ir": false, "is": false }, { "name": "il", "ir": false, "is": false }, { "name": "ibId", "children": [ { "name": "ib1", "ir": false, "is": false }, { "name": "ib2", "ir": false, "is": false } ], "ir": false, "is": false } ], "ir": false, "is": false } ] } ]'

// console.log(JSON.parse(input))

const convertToObject = (data) => {
  const { name, children, ...others } = data
  if(!children) return others;
  
 
  return children.reduce((acc, d) => {
    acc[d['name']] = convertToObject(d);
    return acc;
  }, {})
 
}

console.log(convertToObject({ 'children': JSON.parse(input) }))
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use recursion, as others pointed. I'm adding another variation of this solution

```js
const input = [ { "name": "DI", "children": [ { "name": "t", "children": [ { "name": "tID", "ir": true, "is": false }, { "name": "tTime", "ir": false, "is": false } ], "ir": false, "is": false }, { "name": "i", "idx": 0, "children": [ { "name": "idu", "ir": false, "is": false }, { "name": "il", "ir": false, "is": false }, { "name": "ibId", "children": [ { "name": "ib1", "ir": false, "is": false }, { "name": "ib2", "ir": false, "is": false } ], "ir": false, "is": false } ], "ir": false, "is": false } ] } ]

 
const finalObj = {}

function constructObj(arr, finalObj) {
 for (let obj of arr) {
   if (obj.name) {
     finalObj[obj.name] = {}
     
     if (obj.ir != null) {
       finalObj[obj.name].ir = obj.ir
     }
     
     if (obj.is != null) {
       finalObj[obj.name].is = obj.is
     }
     
     if (obj.children)
       constructObj(obj.children, finalObj[obj.name])
   }
 }
}

constructObj(input, finalObj)
console.log(finalObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use recursive to convert, same as :

```js
const input = [{
  "name": "DI",
  "children": [{
      "name": "t",
      "children": [{
          "name": "tID",
          "ir": true,
          "is": false
        },
        {
          "name": "tTime",
          "ir": false,
          "is": false
        }
      ],
      "ir": false,
      "is": false
    },
    {
      "name": "i",
      "children": [{
          "name": "idu",
          "ir": false,
          "is": false
        },
        {
          "name": "il",
          "ir": false,
          "is": false
        },
        {
          "name": "ibId",
          "children": [{
              "name": "ib1",
              "ir": false,
              "is": false
            },
            {
              "name": "ib2",
              "ir": false,
              "is": false
            }
          ],
          "ir": false,
          "is": false
        }
      ],
      "ir": false,
      "is": false
    }
  ]
}]

const convertToObj = arr => {
  return arr.reduce((res, {name, children, ...rest}) => {
    res[name] = Object.assign(children ? convertToObj(children) : {}, rest )
    return {...res}
  }, {})
}
const result = convertToObj(input)
console.log(result)
```